# What packages sections are available for Trusty?

Tags: 14.04, packaging

I created a new package containing a Unity theme that I would like to update to a PPA. Peeking at [the list of available sections for Trusty](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/) I assigned this simple package to "Miscellaneous". I.e., the `debian/control` file contains the following line:

```
Section: Miscellaneous
```

I am able to upload the package with `dput` without errors. However, I receive back a rejection email with the message:

```
Rejected:
the-package_0.1-1ubuntu1.dsc: Unknown section 'Miscellaneous'
the-package_0.1-1ubuntu1.tar.gz: Unknown section 'Miscellaneous'
```

I tried to comment out the `Section:` line in the `control` file, but I receive a similar rejection message:

```
Rejected:
the-package_0.1-1ubuntu1.dsc: Unknown section '-'
the-package_0.1-1ubuntu1.tar.gz: Unknown section '-'
```

Which section should I use exactly? Is there a list available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you go](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-archive.html#s-subsections):

> 2.4 Sections
>
> The packages in the archive areas main, contrib and non-free are grouped further into sections to simplify handling.
>
> The archive area and section for each package should be specified in the package's Section control record (see Section, Section 5.6.5). However, the maintainer of the Debian archive may override this selection to ensure the consistency of the Debian distribution. The Section field should be of the form:
>
> **section** if the package is in the main archive area,
>
> **area/section** if the package is in the contrib or non-free archive areas.
>
> The Debian archive maintainers provide the authoritative list of sections. At present, they are: **admin, cli-mono, comm, database, debug, devel, doc, editors, education, electronics, embedded, fonts, games, gnome, gnu-r, gnustep, graphics, hamradio, haskell, httpd, interpreters, introspection, java, kde, kernel, libdevel, libs, lisp, localization, mail, math, metapackages, misc, net, news, ocaml, oldlibs, otherosfs, perl, php, python, ruby, science, shells, sound, tasks, tex, text, utils, vcs, video, web, x11, xfce, zope**, The additional section debian-installer contains special packages used by the installer and is not used for normal Debian packages.

---

So "misc".